# Listview + BaseAdapter - how to notify about change in single item?

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have a list view fed by BaseAdapter.

When something changes in data, I call BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged. All works fine.

Now I wonder, **if I change some tiny detail in some list item, is there some optimized way to update view of single item if it's displayed on screen**? 
I suppose that notifyDataSetChanged blindly rebuilds views of all visible items in list, which is not optimal if trivial change in item happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is way. Assuming I can identify list item, for example by assigning View.setTag to it to some value, I can iterate list items and rebind only one list item if desired, or even update only some sub-view of the item.

It's simple and relatively cheap (linear search):

```
for(int i = list.getChildCount(); --i>=0; ){
   View v = list.getChildAt(i);
   Object id = v.getTag();
   if(id==myId){
      updateListItem(id, v);
      break;
   }
}
```

where myId is some ID of item I want to update, and updateListItem makes desired changes on the list item. Proved, and working fine and very efficiently.

Comment: Seems possible, not sure if there is any performance hit ? With this, I can delay to change whole codes to recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

No, I guess it's not possible unless you implement your own `ListView` class extension.
Here there is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) for `setAdapter()`.

You will see, the `ListView` only registers itself as observer using `mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);`
And a `DataSetObserver` provides no means to notify about a change at a certain position.

However it might not be necessary to notify about updates of certain items, because as far as I know, a `ListView` only renders and updates the items currently seen on the screen so, no optimization should be necessary here.